# Deletion in dynamic array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, time-complexity, dynamic-arrays

Can anyone explain the time complexity of (***deletion at ending in dynamic array***)?

I think the answer is **O(1)**

But in book its mentioned **O(n)**.

Comment: What kind of "dynamic array"?

Comment: Is it because you have to search the element you want to delete before deleting? Searching O(n)

Comment: @EngineeredBrain no i am talking about just removing last element whatever it be!

Comment: @ice1000 google it! Its a data structure type like arraylist in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are talking about dynamic arrays, that is, arrays with the ability to add/remove elements to/from them, there are two possible solutions to implement a dynamic array:

1. You allocate *enough* memory to hold all the current and future elements. Also, you need to know the last possible index. Using this setup, the complexity of removing the last element is **O(1)**, since you just decrement the last index. However, removing a non-last element has a linear complexity, since you need to copy all the later elements to the previous before you decrement the last index. Also, you might have difficulty in identifying the maximum possible size at allocation time, possibly leading to overflow issues or memory waste.
2. You can implement it using a list. This way you will not know what the address of the last element is, so you will need to iterate your list till the penultimate item and then free the memory of the last item and set the next of the penultimate item to point to nil. Since the book mentioned a complexity of **O(n)** to remove the last element, we can safely assume that by dynamic array, the book meant this second option.